# Latest Anaconda conflicts with Xcode

Tags: macos, python, xcode, anaconda

I am running conda version 4.6.14 under MacOS 10.13.6 and is seeing the following problem:

Anaconda seems to be setting variables like CC, CXX and so on, eg.

```
CXX=/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
```

This causes conflicts with the existing Xcode installation, and simple ./configure's will fail when trying to build projects.

For now I have just commented out the following from .bash_profile:

```
# <<< conda init <<<
# added by Anaconda3 2019.03 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

and replaced it with a simple

```
export PATH=<path to conda>
```

My question is - is this the expected behaviour from anaconda? Is there anything I can do to avoid having to edit my .bash_profile to rid myself of the corrupted variable space?